# How can I copy media image to clipboard as format image Powershell

Tags: powershell

The idea is to create a script in power shell that receives an URL image as a parameter and then the script will copy that image into clipboard imitating the same behave when I go to any web page and press right-click on any image and select copy image  option.

The way I check if the image was copied into the clipboard is running this command: `Get-Clipboard -format image`

```
Get-Clipboard -format image

Tag                  :
PhysicalDimension    : {Width=1268, Height=664}
Size                 : {Width=1268, Height=664}
Width                : 1268
Height               : 664
HorizontalResolution : 96
VerticalResolution   : 96
Flags                : 335888
RawFormat            : [ImageFormat: b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e]
PixelFormat          : Format32bppRgb
Palette              : System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette
FrameDimensionsList  : {7462dc86-6180-4c7e-8e3f-ee7333a7a483}
PropertyIdList       : {}
PropertyItems        : {}
```

My question is how can I get that kind of copy as same way as I do manually using right-click and selecting "copy image" option?

URL example: https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/zZnP8/s3/2020-rimac-c-two.jpg
I am using google chrome to do that manually

- step 1: I go to google and search for any image like cars for example
- step 2: right-click on any image result and chose "copy image" option
- step 3: go to power shell and  run `Get-Clipboard -format image`
- step 4: power shell will show image info.

[Manual image copy screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmt4P.jpg)

Comment: From where does the image to copy come from? a file or a custom form?

Comment: If you want to right click an image and "Send to Powershell Script" you'll have to hook the normal context menu to add an option - should be possible but not something I;ve looked into..

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I use google chrome, on windows 10